# Create dynamically multiple EditText with ImageView and set ImageView click value to EditText and get value from EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-contacts, savestate

I want to create dynamically `EditText` and `ImageView` on button click.

`ImageView` pick single contact from contact list and set to the `EditText`.  `EditText` also take value from user.  I want to get data of all `EditText` and store the value in `SharedPreference`.

**HelpAlertActivity**

```
public class HelpAlertActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public SharedPreferences sharedpreference;
LinearLayout add_new_layout, mainLayout, image_btn_layout, buttonLayout;
FrameLayout frameLayout;
Button btn_one, bt_submit;
MyEditText et_one, et_two, etAdd;
ImageView image_one, image_two;
ImageButton imageButton;
FloatingActionButton fab;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
List<MyEditText> allEds;
List<ImageView> allImg;
ImageView imageView;
String contactOne, contactTwo, number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, number6, number7, number8, number9, number10, number11,
        number12, number13;
StringBuilder stringBuilder;
GetContact mGetContact;
private int counter = 2, many = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_alert);
    initialization();
}

private void initialization() {
    sharedpreference = getSharedPreferences("preference", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    editor = sharedpreference.edit();

    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    image_btn_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_btn_layout);
   /* buttonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);
    add_new_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newLayout);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);*/
    mGetContact = new GetContact();
    et_one = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_one);
    et_two = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_two);
    image_one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_one);
    image_two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_two);
 //   btn_one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
    bt_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_submit);
    image_one.setOnClickListener(this);
    image_two.setOnClickListener(this);
  //  btn_one.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt_submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.btn_one:
            if (this.counter < 10) {
                LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
                LinearLayout childView = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                etAdd = generateEditText(counter+1);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(45, 45);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 25, 20, 0);
                imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_contact);
                imageView.setId(counter+1);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(handler);
               /* imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), counter+1);
                    }
                });*/
                //getValue(imageView);

                allEds.add(etAdd);
                allImg.add(imageView);
                childView.addView(etAdd);
                childView.addView(imageView);
                parentView.addView(childView);

                counter++;
                //many++;
                //editor.putInt("no_of_layouts", many);
            } else {
                // v.setEnabled(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.image_one:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 1);
            break;
        case R.id.image_two:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 2);
            break;
        case R.id.bt_submit:
            String ctone = et_one.getText().toString();
            String ct_two = et_two.getText().toString();
            //int size = allEds.size();
            // String[] strings = new String[size];
           /* for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {

                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();

                editor.putString("contact" + i, strings[i]);
                Log.e("Added number", "" + i);
                // Toast.makeText(this, "contact" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
            if (ctone.equals("") && ctone.isEmpty() || ct_two.equals("") && ct_two.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter mobile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                editor.putString("contactOne", ctone);
                editor.putString("contactTwo", ct_two);
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                //  }

                break;
            }
        /*case R.id.fab:
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image_btn_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;*/
    }
}

View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case 3:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 3);
                break;
            case 4:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 4);
                break;
            case 5:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 5);
                break;
            case 6:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 6);
                break;
            case 7:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 7);
                break;
            case 8:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 8);
                break;
            case 9:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 9);
                break;
            case 10:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 10);
                break;
            case 11:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 11);
                break;
            case 12:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 12);
                break;
            case 13:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 13);
                break;
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String num = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                Log.e("ADDED NUMBER", num);
                et_one.setText(num.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number2 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                Log.e("ADDED NUMBERo", number2);
                et_two.setText(number2.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number3 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number3.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number4 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number4.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number5 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number5.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number6 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number6.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number7 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number7.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number8 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number8.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number9 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number9.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 10:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number10 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number10.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 11:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number11 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number11.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 12:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number12 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number12.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;
        case 13:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                number13 = mGetContact.getdetails(data, getApplicationContext());
                etAdd.setText(number13.replaceAll("[- ]", ""));
            }
            break;

    }

}

 public MyEditText generateEditText(int id) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 90, 1.0f);
    layoutParams.setMargins(15, 10, 0, 0);
    MyEditText et = new MyEditText(this);
    et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(13)});
    et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_textfield_background);
    et.setHint("Enter or Select number");
    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    et.setPadding(35, 0, 30, 0);
    et.setId(id);
    et.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return et;
}

 /* @Override
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}*/

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   contactOne = sharedpreference.getString("contactOne", null);
   contactTwo = sharedpreference.getString("contactTwo", null);
    //*for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {
       // stringBuilder.append(sharedpreference.getString("contact" + i, "") + ",");
    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    et_one.setText(contactOne);
    et_two.setText(contactTwo);
    //* int size = allEds.size();
    // String[] strings = new String[size];
    // String[] lines = stringBuilder.toString().split(",");
    // for (String s : lines) {
    //  etAdd.setText(s);
 /**//*   strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
    sharedpreference.getString("contact" + i, "");*//**//*
    }*//*

}*/
}
}

/* public ImageView generateImageView(int id) {
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(45, 45);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 25, 20, 0);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_contact);
imageView.setId(id);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
return imageView;
}*/
```

## acitivity_help_alert.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <test.com.helpalert.MyEditText
            android:id="@+id/contact_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:background="@drawable/login_textfield_background"
            android:hint="@string/contact_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_one"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add_contact"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <test.com.helpalert.MyEditText
            android:id="@+id/contact_two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:background="@drawable/login_textfield_background"
            android:hint="@string/contact_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_two"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add_contact"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/image_btn_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add_circular_button"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/btn_submit"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

## GetContact

```
public class GetContact {

String num = "";
public String getdetails(Intent data, Context applicationContext) {
    Cursor c = null;
    Cursor numbers = null;
    try {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
         c = applicationContext.getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String hasNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if (Integer.valueOf(hasNumber) == 1) {
                numbers = applicationContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (numbers.moveToNext())
                    num = numbers.getString(numbers.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }
        }
    }finally {
        if(c!=null  ){
            c.close();
        }
    }
    return num;
}
}
```

Comment: So, which part of the code are you having troubles?

Comment: phone number is showing in edittext but I am unable to get data from editText.

Answer (score 1):

When you click submit, you should go in a loop looking for all the added `EditText`s and getting value from them.

Try this:

```
String ct_one = et_one.getText().toString();
String ct_two = et_two.getText().toString();

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
int index = 3; // the first dynamic id
MyEditText editText = (MyEditText) findViewById(index);
while (editText != null) {
    strings.add(editText.getText().toString());
}

Log.d("found strings: " + ct_one + ", " + ct_two + ", and: " + Arrays.toString(strings));
```

**UPDATE**

Your SharedPreferences code is a bit strange, first you should use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` unless you have a good reason to use a different file.
second, you should `commit`/`apply` your edits immediately after editing, not keep an open editor object.

To write values:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("value_one", ct_one);
editor.putString("value_two", ct_two);
for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    editor.putString("value" + i, strings.get(i));
}
editor.apply(); // actually saves the edits into the prefs file
```

To read values:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String ct_one = prefs.getString("value_one");
String ct_two = prefs.getString("value_two");
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;
while (prefs.contains("value" + i)) {
    strings.add(prefs.getString("value" + i));
}
```

BTW, if the order of the strings is not important, you can use `putStringSet`/`getStringSet` instead of the loop code

Comment: Thanks @marmor it's working.Can please tell me how can I persit that data when app start again.I haved tried sharedprefrecence but it is not working.

Comment: It's really helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a project to create cookbook recipe. When I add a recipe I can have multiple ingredients and multiple state of preparation.

The big problem is to know how many and to store all the edit text in one string (I store only one string with line feed character).

I find another solution on this site : https://prasans.info/add-edittexts-dynamically-and-retrieve-values-android/.

To be easiest the intesting part is from create list of edit text and each time you create one you add in. The best thing is I now can create two list one for ingredients and one for states.

In the beginning of the activity :

```
private ArrayList<EditText> ListEditText = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you create new edit text (just with .addView) :

```
ListEditText.add(new_editText);
```

When you want to get the information :

```js
String text = "";
for (EditText editText : ListEditText) {
  text += editText.getText().toString() + "\n";
}
// display text
```